# ionic 1 app showing white screen after splash screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have done my app completely . But when i try to check in my device its fine. But my client want me to send the `apk build` to check. I have send him using this commands `sudo cordova build android` then i took the apk adn i send to my client. But after splash screen - its coming white screen.

But in my device its working fine.here my `index.html`:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- userdefined css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/tab.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="lib/ionic/fonts/ArconRegular.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <script data-require="google-maps@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>

    <script data-require="lodash-underscore@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/2.4.1/dist/lodash.underscore.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="angular-google-maps@*" data-semver="1.1.4" src="https://rawgit.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/1.1.4/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>



    <script src="ionic-ion-autoListDivider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic-drawer.js"></script> 

    <script src="js/factories.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>


    <!-- Chance.js is only used to generate random data -->  
    <script src="lib/chance/chance.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <!-- For AutoComplete box -->
    <script src="lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.directive.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="CRM">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added this lie in my `config.xml` too:

`<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />`

I am using `ASUS`. But my client tested in `redmi 3, moto,nexus`

Please help me out. Why its working in my device. But not working in my client testing devices ??

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try with reducing this value and check in both devices

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary which value ??. And i removed `<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />` this line also. working in my device, with my same wifi that i have done `sudo cordova build android`... should i need to use `ionic release` to use that apk in my clinet device with different wifi

Comment: try the same with available device,if its fine then only release....if u dont have those devices use third partie genymotion,android studio to produce such kind of devices